# Using a loop, merge two dataframes and subset by group

Tags: r, loops

I have 2 data frames with 85 different IDs, and 40 different groups, so **I'd like to use a loop** as it is too much data to go through by hand.

Here's what I need to do:

I want to merge the two data frames by ID for **each group**, make a new column that multiplies Data X Area, then extract separate csvs by each group. Each ID in each group has a different area, but number of IDs is the same per group.

Here's the dummy data:

```
Group <- c(100,100,100,103,103,103,110,110,110)
ID <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
Area <- c(23,4,3,23,0,.5,7,2,33)

x <- data.frame(Group, ID, Area)

ID <- c(1,2,3)
Data <- c(.002,.4,1)

y <- data.frame(ID, Data)
```

Desired Output (different csv for each group):

```
Group    ID    Area    Data    A.D
 100      1     23      .002   .046
 100      2     4       .4     1.6
 100      3     3        1      3
```

Comment: have a look at `?merge` and `?split`

Comment: is there are group id for `y`, how do you plan to determine which id in `y` matches to which id in `x`?

Comment: @NathanDay - no, there isn't... I was hoping to extract by `group` first, then merge the `ID`. As the `group` is tied to the unique `area`

Comment: @HubertL - I looked at split... But can I do something in a loop instead of splitting them manually?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: so lets say we are talking about group100, how do we know which `y$Data` value to use when there are 3 that match to `ID = 1`

Comment: A nice resource: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: @NathanDay - you are right, I typed the data wrong. Each `ID` in `y` is unique. Thank you for catching that!

Comment: for your last step - you can just split the joined data frame by group into a list of dataframes using `split` and then use `sapply` and `write.csv` to output all of them at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could do it with `base`:

1) Get all of your data together in `z` and perform your new column calculation:

```
z <- merge(x, y)
z$data_x_aread <- z$Data * z$Area
```

2) Now split `z` by group so it is a list of 3 `data.frames`:

```
df_list <-  split(z, Group)
```

3) Grab the element names from `df_list` (these are really just the  group names). And make valid path strings with `paste0`. We will store these in a character vector:

```
vector_of_output_paths <- paste0("~/Desktop/", names(df_list), ".csv")
```

4) Take advantage of `mapply` and use it to write the csv's sourcing the `data.frames` to write from `df_list` and the respective file path's for each from `vector_of_output_paths`:

```
mapply(write.csv, df_list, vector_of_output_paths)
```

Comment: It works! Though I made a small edit here: `vector_of_output_paths <- paste0("", names(df_list), ".csv")` For some reason, the files were being names Desktop100, Desktop102, etc. because of that argument, and they only need to be named by group. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you could just remove that first term "" in `paste0`, perhaps the original was missing the "/" after Desktop causing ti behave like that. Either way as long as they are outputting to a location you can find, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, you might be able to do sth. like:

```
library(dplyr)
merge(x, y, by = c("ID")) %>% 
  mutate(A.D = Area * Data) %>%
  arrange(Group)
```

Which yields:

```
  ID Group Area  Data    A.D
1  1   100 23.0 0.002  0.046
2  2   100  4.0 0.400  1.600
3  3   100  3.0 1.000  3.000
4  1   103 23.0 0.002  0.046
5  2   103  0.0 0.400  0.000
6  3   103  0.5 1.000  0.500
7  1   110  7.0 0.002  0.014
8  2   110  2.0 0.400  0.800
9  3   110 33.0 1.000 33.000
```

Comment: That does work! I'll try it with the large dataset, thanks Jan. Do you know if there is a quick way to extract different CSVs by `Group`?

Comment: Have a look at `group_by()` from the `dplyr` package.